# Offer a trial of an in-app purchase

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-store

I want to have users be able to try out functionality that is usually a paid one.

Making a paid app have a trial is built in to the store. How about this in-app trial, is there a way to have that? If so - how? (C#/XAML.)

Comment: I think you should be able to achieve what you want by providing another IAP, durable (time-limited) and with discounted/free price.

Comment: @Romasz Thanks. But how would I create a time-limited IAP?

Comment: When you create a durable IAP, you [can set product lifetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/apps/mt148534.aspx) - from 1 to 365 days (or 0 for forever).

Comment: @Romasz Perfect! I didn't know about that. You can transform your comments into an answer.

Comment: do you use a database of any sort to store a user's account information or other information?  if so, you can avoid all users having to discover your IAP, and just enable it for all and keep track of the expiration date for this feature in your db.  Purchasing the "real" IAP would extend this same date in your db.  I use this technique successfully in my app.

Comment: @KoryGill Thanks. But my app doesn't connect to any server and I'd like to keep it that way. So I actually don't have a complete solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot provide a trial version for IAP straight forward.

But what you want to achieve, should be easy to perform by providing second time-limited (durable) IAP, time limited. When you take a look [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/apps/mt148534.aspx) you will see that you can set *product lifetime* from 1 to 365 days (or 0 for forever). You can of course set any proce for the second IAP, even free.

The only thing, I think you will have to handle is the case when trial expires and user tries to buy another free IAP. In this case you will probably have to [check app receipt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt219692.aspx).

More useful information you will find at [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt219687.aspx).

Comment: +1. Thanks again. But unfortunately my app doesn't connect to a server and I would like to keep it that way.

Comment: @ispiro What do you mean that your app 'doesn't connect to a server'? You mean windows store? Your users install the app without MS store?

Comment: No. I mean that the app runs on the user's computer without accessing the internet (after it's been installed). So the app can't check the receipt. And therefore the user would be able to get the free trial multiple times. (From the link you provided: `After you get a receipt, you need your back-end system (a web service or something similar) to validate it. `.)

Comment: @ispiro To buy an IAP the user has to connect to the store, and I'm not sure if product lifetime is not stored somewhere in the system - I think it should, in other case the problem you have described would be very common.

Comment: `I'm not sure if product lifetime is not stored somewhere in the system` - If I could access that - that would be great.

Comment: @ispiro I think (I'm not sure) that you can try something like this: provide an IAP, time limited, the users buys it, the time expires so the user has to buy it again - so connect to the store. Once he clicks buy trial IAP, first, you get app receipt from the store and check if he hasn't bought the IAP before. In this case I think, the best would be to check this with a beta app - provide a one day IAP, then try it with offline device for one day and you will know everything.

Comment: I don't think so, otherwise think about the case where someone bought the IAP on one machine, and wants to run the app on another.  Running disconnected from some time is okay, but eventually, you need to re-sync. Only other solution I can think of is *security through obscurity* (store a date in a file, registry, etc.) which of course is not a solution.

Comment: @KoryGill Any chance you can get your colleagues to do something about it? :)

Comment: @KoryGill You mean that license info is not stored in system/app somewhere? And if it's offline it can work for ever with limited IAP?

Comment: @Romasz, I probably did not word my last comment as well as I could have, since I think this question is running into more dead-ends as it unfolds. I have never tested whether `licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["featureName"].IsActive` works without network connection, and for how long.

Comment: @KoryGill Neither do I, that's why I proposed this beta test, which should 'show everything'. Unfortunately, now I don't have time to perform such one, but probably will do this in future, if nobody solves the issue before.