# Can an app discover its acquisition date?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-store

Can an app discover its acquisition date without the need for a web service (besides the windows store)?

I need this in order to create a trial for an in-app purchase.

(This is a semi-follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842908/offer-a-trial-of-an-in-app-purchase))

Comment: I'm not sure if that will be possible. But maybe you can think of storing the datetime of the very first run, somewhere in localsettings?

Comment: @Romasz That's what  [Kory Gill](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842908/offer-a-trial-of-an-in-app-purchase#comment57427830_34843277) suggested, and correctly concluded `"which of course is not a solution"`. But thanks. (The reason that security by obscurity is not a solution is that it can be discovered and circumvented.)

Comment: Yeah, right. Unfortunately, I don't think you will be able to get any information from system. Another idea which comes to my mind (a shoot in the dark this time) - maybe you can check the time when any of the files in installed location (read-only) has been created/modified?

Comment: @Romasz Better. But still not enough. Anyone who acquires a license can uninstall and reinstall the app. And uninstalling removes all of those files.  (As far as I know.) That's why acquisition time is important, not installation time.

Comment: Yeah, right, this disqualifies the file method. I'm run out of ideas :|

Comment: You can use the roamingSettings which last for 30 days after uninstallation

Comment: @the_nuts But roaming settings still need connection to internet to synchronize.

Comment: @Romasz Thanks for your perseverance. A workaround might be to have two parallel types of the same app on the store - one free+IAPs and the other trial+paid (with every possible functionality) and have the free one mention that to test the IAPs - one can download the paid version as a trial. Ugly, but I can't seem to find any other way of achieving this. Thanks again.

Comment: @the_nuts This might partially work. But after 30 days, the user will be able to get the trial again. But thanks for that information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App and in-app-product purchase date is available in the receipt's AppReceipt and ProductReceipt fields.
See [CurrentApp.GetAppReceiptAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.getappreceiptasync.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.getappreceiptasync.aspx) implies we should verify a receipt's authenticity. Why? We're not told to do that with [CurrentApp.LicenseInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.licenseinformation).

Comment: Why do I care? Because I'd either have to spend a long time implementing/learning something that should have been simple, or use [MSDN's code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt219692.aspx) without understanding it, which is a bad idea. Do you know what's the actual problem here? (- how this could be exploited.)

Comment: I'll ad another thing - this isn't useful for deciding about an app's functionality because this method needs (as far as I understand) an internet connection. The app must work offline as well.

Comment: The verification step is for a server passed the receipt, not for a client receiving the receipt directly from Windows. This lets the server know that it's a legit receipt and it should provide the purchased data. If you stay within context that originally acquired the receipt then separate verification isn't relevant.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. (Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be useful for trial managing because it seems to need to be online. But it's good to know for future reference.)